# Method asyncio.streams.StreamReader.read(byte_count) reads too few bytes

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have observed some rare behaviour with asyncio/Python3.4/Windows7 where `asyncio.streams.StreamReader.read(byte_count)` reads fewer than `byte_count` bytes.  I am unable to reliably reproduce the behaviour, but with enough network activity (1000s of reads), I might see it *once*.

The documentation for `read(byte_count)` says:  `Read up to n bytes.`

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#streamreader

The English phrase "up to" indicates it might sometimes read less(!).  As I originally understood the coroutine's behavior: It will not return until the expected number of bytes is received.

1. Do I understand `read(byte_count)` correctly?
2. Has anyone else observed this same behaviour?

My current workaround is to check the number of bytes received.  If incomplete, call `read(byte_count)` again with remaining byte count.  (But this seems to defeat the purpose of `read(byte_count)`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you understand correctly: `read(n)` might return less than `n`. That's normal, and you should repeat reading until you either get no more bytes due to EOF or some error.

Answer (score 3):

You should use StreamReader.readexactly() instead of StreamReader.read():
"Read exactly n bytes."
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.readexactly